# Detect GridView bottom and up

Tags: android, gridview

I have to visible next-previous option on GridView bottom and and invisible if GridView is not on bottom.I used following code it works good but in a particular situation both if and else condition call so next-previous layout start blinking.

**Code:**

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (mGridView.getLastVisiblePosition() == mGridView.getAdapter()
                    .getCount() - 1
                    && mGridView.getChildAt(mGridView.getChildCount() - 1)
                            .getBottom() <= mGridView.getHeight()) {
                // End has been reached
                Animation slideUpIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getActivity(), R.anim.side_in);
                mFooterView.startAnimation(slideUpIn);
                mFooterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mFooterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

    }
```

any suggestion will be great appreciated.

Comment: your `if (mGridView.getLastVisiblePosition() == mGridView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1 && mGridView.getChildAt(mGridView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= mGridView.getHeight())` is creating a Lag

Comment: yeah this condition creating problem in sometime not always but it creates prob and if I keep gridview in same state then if and else start calling so My layout starts blinking

Answer (score 0):

your `if (mGridView.getLastVisiblePosition() == mGridView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1 && mGridView.getChildAt(mGridView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= mGridView.getHeight())` is creating a Lag.

In `onScroll()`:

`totalItemCount` is `mGridView.getAdapter().getCount()`
`firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount` is `mGridView.getLastVisiblePosition()`

Refer this Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll(android.widget.AbsListView, int, int, int)

**Edit:**
`if(firstVisibleItem == 0) means you are on the top.`

And For Bottom of the List:

```
if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount){
    // End has been reached
}
```

**Edit: Detect Scroll Up-Down**

```
int myLastVisiblePos = 0; //global variable in the activity class

gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int currentFirstVisPos = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            if(currentFirstVisPos > myLastVisiblePos) {
                //scroll down
            }
            if(currentFirstVisPos < myLastVisiblePos) {
                //scroll up
            }
            myLastVisiblePos = currentFirstVisPos;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks it's really helpful I wanna detect gridView start scrolling towards top